# Pandas keeping other columns after GroupBy - Not a sum

Tags: python, pandas

Following data set represent a user's browsing behavior.

```
  user_id session_id        keyword        real_time_stamp           presented    clicked
0  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  101           101
1  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  102           None
2  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  103           None
3  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  104           None
4  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  105           None
5  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  106           None
6  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  107           None
7  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  108           None
8  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  109           None
9  10010  s2342009n           camera 2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  110           None
```

Presented column shows what items were presented to the user and and from the presented items which one was clicked. In above example 1st items was clicked. Goal is to bring this information into one row but also keep the time stamp.

By doing following `group_by` gives the structure but its without `real_time_stamp` and `clicked`. Once you ad `real_time_stamp` to the group by you don't get the "aggregated" version.

```
df_collapse = df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_id', 'keyword'])['presented'].apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x)).reset_index()
```

My attempt is to get following structure:

```
   user_id session_id        keyword        real_time_stamp                 presented                               clicked
     10010  s2342009n       camera     2020-03-01 05:00:19.195000+00:00  101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110      101
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC check with `transform`

```
s=df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_id', 'keyword'])['presented'].transform(lambda x: '|'.join(x.astype(str)))
df['New']=s
```

if agg to one

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'session_id', 'keyword']).\
    agg({'presented':'|'.join,
         'real_time_stamp':'first',
         'clicked':'first'})
```